# What is the overall safest way to use Tor?

Tags: security

I have reason to believe that I my status or activities place me at particular risk. I would like to do everything that I can to keep safe while using Tor. I think that I should get a dedicated computer, but I don't know how to set it up, or stay safe while using it.

What are the things that an at-risk person like me should do to set up a particularly safe computer to use Tor on? Are there any risks that I should remain aware of, of that this setup won't protect me from? Are there any things that I should make sure always/never to do when using a setup like this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for extreme security, I would suggest using Tails, or running Tor inside a virtual machine.  A popular, pre-configured virtual machine/Tor setup is Whonix, which claims to prevent IP address leaks.  Other than that, these are some ideas:

Getting a dedicated computer is a little extreme, and probably unnecessary if using a virtual machine.  Learn how to configure your firewall, keep your software up-to-date, use anti-virus software when applicable, and find a good secure-erase tool.  Tails comes with encryption software; learn to use that as well.  Using public WiFi is a great way to keep attention away from your home IP, although as long as your aren't worried about a breakout Whonix should be sufficient for this.  To answer your second and third questions: https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning

I suggest you read the Tor Project [documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en) and [wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki), and remember:  there is no perfect security, and there are attacks that even Tor does not defend against, if the adversary is powerful enough.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the latest version of [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en).

But if you think your computer might have been compromised, the next easy step is to burn a Live Linux, like Ubuntu on a CD. Boot your computer with that live CD, and use Tor Browser Bundle to surf the internet. You may also use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/), which has been configure to use Tor by default.

Make sure you read these two warnings before using Tor or Tails.

"[Want Tor to really work?](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning)" and "[Tails Warning Page](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning/index.en.html)"